# Android - Missing NDK Platforms?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Have a look at the following terminal paste from my system. As you will be able to see, I seem to have several SDK platforms installed for which there is no NDK avaiable:

```
rutski@electron:~/Documents/sdk/android-ndk/platforms$ android list targets | grep 'android-'
id: 1 or "android-3"
id: 2 or "android-4"
id: 3 or "android-7"
id: 4 or "android-8"
id: 5 or "android-10"
id: 6 or "android-11"
id: 7 or "android-12"
id: 8 or "android-13"
rutski@electron:~/Documents/sdk/android-ndk/platforms$ ls
android-3  android-4  android-5  android-8  android-9
```

What's the deal here? Is my NDK install broken, or is there a good reason for this?

It also seems that I have android-9 as an NDK, but not as an SDK; but I swear, I installed all SDKs available with the android(1) GUI tool.

Comment: updating NDK in android studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660659/how-to-update-android-ndk-in-place/42771211#42771211

Answer (score 1):

According to the NDK documentation, what would have been `android-6` and `android-7` is the same as `android-5`. My guess is that now they are simply dropping out duplicate directories, and that the API levels not shown are handled by the next available one.

If you are experiencing actual symptoms (e.g., can't build an NDK app for Honeycomb), post a question with a description of those symptoms, either here or on the `android-ndk` Google Group. If you are not experiencing symptoms and are simply confused by the directory structure, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: the missing NDKs are causing problems in practice. For example, when attempting to port/build a library for API 17, you will encounter missing headers. See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159910/android-ndk-r8e-missing-stdlib-h.