# Android NDK R8E missing stdlib.h

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm testing some native library code with the Android NDK (android-ndk-r8e). The native library is being built from its makefile rather than Android's modified build system. Using the makefile rather than Android's build system is a project requirement (OpenSSL and FIPS).

The library needs to be built for API 14 (Android 4.0), API 16 (Android 4.1), and API 17 (Android 4.2). Though its using the library's makefile, we are using the prebuilt toolchain from android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64 (arm-linux-androideabi-4.7 and friends).

It appears `stdlib.h` is missing from 2 of the 3 APIs. For example, below is an attempt to compile for API 17.

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_FIPSCANISTER -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC
-DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -march=armv7-a
-mandroid -I/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/include
-B/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-17/arch-arm/usr/lib -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall
-DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DAES_ASM
-DGHASH_ASM -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
In file included from cryptlib.c:117:0:
cryptlib.h:62:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
```

Based on feedback from Auselen and Chris, I tried to build a toolchain for API 17. It failed:

```
$ $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-17 --install-dir=./android-testAuto-config: --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6
Invalid platform name: android-17
Please use --platform=<name> with one of: android-14 android-3 android-4 android-5 android-8 android-9
```

How does one handle missing headers in the NDK?

---

```
$ find /opt/android-ndk-r8e/ -iname stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-mips/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-x86/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-mips/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-x86/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-4/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/tr1/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include/tr1/stdlib.h
/opt/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.4.3/include/tr1/stdlib.h
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a [standalone toolchain](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ics-mr0/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html) from NDK, and use that one to build your native library.
You will probably need to modify environment variables like `CC`, `LD` on the command line or inside Makefile to point to this new toolchain's `gcc`. Something like:

```
CC="arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=$SYS_ROOT"
LD="arm-linux-androideabi-ld"
```

Comment: Thanks auselen. We are using AOSP's prebuilt toolchain from android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2. I updated the question.

Comment: But did you run the script for making a stand alone toolchain?

Comment: Thanks Chris. No, we are using the prebuilt stuff from the NDK.

Comment: @noloader prebuilt AOSP toolchain is something different. You are using NDK, and my answer should help you. May be I should underline `sysroot` argument to `gcc`. Absence of that must lead to missing `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Here's what happened. Run: "$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-17 --install-dir=./android-test". Got back: "Please use --platform=<name> with one of: android-14 android-3 android-4 android-5 android-8 android-9". I already have those (android-3, 4, 5, 8, 14) from the prebuilt stuff in the NDK.

Comment: No, specifying one of the existing android versions will not re-create that toolchain, rather it will create a toolchain with canned adaptations for use in everyday makefiles, rather than one that needs to be used with all of the presets normally configured by an NDK project makefile as is the case for the toolchain your tried to use.  This built-in pre-configuration is what we mean by a stand-alone toolchain.

Comment: @noloader Read $NDK/docs/STABLE-APIS.html for available platform versions. android-14 is for ´Android 4.0´ system images and that should be enough for you, and in fact it is the latest available one.