# How to update Android NDK in place?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I used to download the Android NDK as new version were pubished to the devloper website.

It appears Google has recently updated the developer website and removed direct NDK download links, and replaced them with a a bunch of circular references that eventually lead to the SDK download. The SDK download page does not include the NDK. The closest I have found to a download and NDK is [Download Android Studio and SDK Tools](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Running `$ sudo /opt/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android` does not offer a way to update the NDK.

How do I update the NDK in place using the existing NDK or one of the SDK tools?

Or where is the download of the actual NDK located?

---

To be clear, I use `ant` and `ndk-build` from the command line. I don't use Eclipse or Android Studio. [Eclipse and the Android plugin is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27910777/608639); and Android Studio does not really support NDK and JNI.

Plus, I don't really want to learn another editor since I kind of know Eclipse, and I know already how to do it from the command line (so there's no need for an editor).

Comment: Is this ok for you? https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 8):

1. In Android Studio, go to `Tools (top-menu item) > Android > SDK Manager`
2. Click SDK Tools tab
3. Scroll down and you will see NDK as an option, with detail if an update is available

[image]

[image]

Comment: in my case android is not showing in that position . how to do that?

Comment: Looks like **SDK Manager** is now a top level menu item under *Tools* menu.  Please feel free to update the image if you'd like

Comment: I cannot find the SDK manager menu now. Perhaps it was moved again?..