# Getting warning "NDK is missing a 'platforms" directory.' with no NDK

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

I've got a project that only uses the Android SDK, not the NDK, but I'm getting warnings whenever I build with gradle about the NDK:

`NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.`

Seems like a pretty clear warning. I'm not using the ndk, so there is no `ndk-bundle` in my `android-sdk`. The issue is that I don't have an `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` set, and my `local.properties` file (which appears to be generated by Android Studio) doesn't set the NDK:

`sdk.dir=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`

I do have an ANDROID_HOME environment variable:

`ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk`

System is a mac, but we seem to get the same issue in Docker. Anyone know how to get rid of this warning?

Comment: `ANDROID_HOME` is usually something like `$HOME/.android`. It is for your local settings, like you Android developer keys. It does not make sense to point it to the SDK directory. The SDK directory is often not writable because it is located at `/opt/android-sdk` or similar.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please refer to these two links:

- [How to fix android studios 2.3 NDK bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682357/how-to-fix-android-studios-2-3-ndk-bug)
- https://github.com/requery/requery/issues/467

> This is caused by upgrading to Android gradle plugin 2.3
>   (com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0).
>
> In previous versions of the plugin the databinding package name (where
>   the BR file is generated) was provided on an annotation in a generate
>   file. In the new version it's passed as a annotation processor option
>   which is now handled.
>
> An updated version will be available soon, a temporary workaround is
>   to simply use the previous android gradle plugin 2.2.2

Comment: I'm getting this warning on gradle plugin 2.3.3!

Comment: Same here, using 2.3.3

Comment: @Pablo: the workaround (at that time) was to back *DOWN* to Gradle 2.2.2.  EXAMPLE BUILD.GRADLE: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

Comment: How do I do this when Unity is managing the android sdk?

Comment: Q: What version of Android Studio are you running.  3.x?