# XML parsing error: how to resolve?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I am new to android Studio and i'm facing some problems during an app development.
It shows xml parsing error: 
no element found so please guys help me.
I have added some screenshots and xml main activity coding. 
A few days ago I also askes a question about this problem, but at that time I didn't attach any screenshot and the xml coding, so I didn't get any good answer.

[Screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLAwr.jpg)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oi79.jpg)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                tools:context="comhanumanbeniwaloffice.facebook.www.hanumanbeniwal.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text="परिचय"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="Latest News"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPressedHighlight"
        android:text="ब्लॉग"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="तस्वीरें"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="विडियो"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="लाइव"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPressedHighlight"
        android:text="Speech"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Contact"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"  />
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: i have edited my previous question but i don't get any response so please tell me what should i do ?

Comment: Well, reposting the question is not what you want to do. You can always edit the original to improve it, add new info, etc., and it will get bumped. Also, you need to post all text as text, not screenshots, so adding your layout XML to the original would bump it. That said, do you have a closing `</RelativeLayout>` tag at the end of your layout?

Comment: Now it is showing :    Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682357/how-to-fix-android-studios-2-3-ndk-bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730178/getting-warning-ndk-is-missing-a-platforms-directory-with-no-ndk