# NDK is missing a "platforms" directory. while trying to build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

> Executing tasks: [clean]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. NDK is missing a
>   "platforms" directory. If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set
>   to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to
>   /Users/ishandutta2007/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle. If you are not
>   using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or
>   local.properties to remove this warning.
>
> Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use
>   'implementation' instead.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.  at
>     org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:87)
>     at
>     org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
>     at
>     org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:69)
>     at
>     org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
>     at
>     org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>     at
>     org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:49)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:651)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:133)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:100)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:81)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$CalculateTaskGraph.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:265)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.constructTaskGraph(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:173)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:128)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>     com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:782)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getPlatformVersion(NdkHandler.java:158)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.supports64Bits(NdkHandler.java:331)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getSupportedAbis(NdkHandler.java:397)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.create(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:609)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createExternalNativeBuildJsonGenerators(TaskManager.java:1532)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.lambda$createTasksForVariantScope$10(ApplicationTaskManager.java:205)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApplicationTaskManager.createTasksForVariantScope(ApplicationTaskManager.java:200)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:523)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.lambda$createAndroidTasks$1(VariantManager.java:338)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:334)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:627)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:622)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$3(BasePlugin.java:549)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$4(BasePlugin.java:545)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)     at
>     org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
>     ... 95 more
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3s

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'org.tensorflow.demo'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:1.3.0'
}
```

Android Studio: 2.3.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix android studios 2.3 NDK bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682357/how-to-fix-android-studios-2-3-ndk-bug)

Comment: Try to set `compileSdkVersion` **`"android-26"`**

Comment: didn't get you,it's already 26.

Comment: Not to use a number, but literal string. And make to use latest NDK.

Answer (score 23):

This probably happens because Android Studio will automatically download the latest version of NDK which doesn't have a `platforms` directory (No idea why! Would be awesome if someone can clarify that).

This is what worked for me. Using the SDK manager. That is the icon in the top right corner of Android Studio that looks like this [image: SDK Manager icon]. Go to SDK Tools tab. In the right bottom corner, enable Show Package Details and install NDK version 20.0.5594570 (You can remove the newer version that was installed automatically by Android Studio to save space).

[image: SDK Manager]

Note that the NDK will be installed in the location shown in Android SDK Location. For me that is set to `/home/<username>/.local/android-sdk`. Which means I can find the NDK at `/home/<username>/.local/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/`

Hit apply and when it's done go to file called `local.properties` and add this.

```
ndk.dir=/home/<username>/.local/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570
```

Adapt the path to where you have your NDK installed.

Comment: i had try this solution before.but it still have the same proble...And i even try open the project structure dialog,and choose the path as you give above, then alert "NDK does not cotainers any platform"....still this.

Comment: the 'platforms' dir for me was just outside the default 'ndk-bundle' folder, instead of inside it, so i simply copied it in, and it worked.... yeah 'no idea why!'... but thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 13):

Very strange, for me ndk version `22.0.7026061` indeed did not have a `platforms` directory. On my disk ndk version `21.1.6352462` had a platforms directory and setting

```
ndk.dir=/home/username/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462
```

on `local.properties` solved the problems.

Comment: Indeed. Neither does 22.1.7171670

Comment: I was looking for this answer for 2 days. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but just ran into this and the File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location - Android NDK Location setting was missing.  Once I filled it in to the "Recommended" one it gradle sync'd fine

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out the core reason, and the solution is:

1. upgrade Gradle and AGP, and set the right NDK configuration.
2. set ndk.dir in local.properties for lower AGP version.

Different AGP(Android Gradle Plugin) versions have different NDK configuration. And most AGP auto download higher NDK version when NDK is not configured, while higher NDK has no platforms dir, which cause an AGP error as shown in `--stacktrace`.

For lower AGP version, like 3.4.x, the only way is set `local.properties` or set NDK location in Android Studio project structure, which is also set NDK location by writing it to `local.properties`, too.

See docs in Android Develop for more details.

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-agp-ndk?language=agp3-5#agp-version

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle

AGP 3.4.x NDK configuration only local.properties.
[image]

AGP 3.5.x NDK configuration support build.gradle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, but the logs are somewhat different, from the logs I could find that it is related to NDK.

Error message that I encountered:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getPlatformVersion(NdkHandler.java:121)
```

Below are the things to check,

1. Check if the NDK is downloaded and configured properly.

Cntrl + Alt + Shift + S, if it configured properly, you should see the location auto populated in the field.

[image]

If not, download update the path in local.properties file.

[image]

2. Check if the gradle build tools are updated.

Open Project gradle file and make sure the dependency that you have downloaded and the dependency in the gradle file are matching.

(Hint: Create a new app, copy and past the version that is generated when you create the app.)

[image]

3. When the above steps are proper, make sure to update gradle-wrapper.properties file with the proper version of gradle distribution,

Hint: If the above 2 steps are properly configured, Android Studio should suggest you to update this url as well.

[image]

Post this, app should build properly, without any issues.

Good Luck...!

Comment: setting the ndkVersion from 22.xxxxx to 21.xxxxxx resolved my similar NDKHandler issue ..

Answer (score -2):

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.

If you are using NDK, verify the `ndk.dir` is set to a valid NDK directory.

It is currently set to `C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle`.

If you are not using NDK, unset the `NDK` variable from `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` or `local.properties` to remove this warning.

Comment: this is by no means an answer, it is even a part of the question!

Answer (score -3):

( android 5.3)We can solve it by removing android NDK plugin from your project. Go to setting ->plugin->android ndk support disable, click apply, click ok

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.

Comment: Yeah, let's just disable something required for building the project...