# NDK is missing a "platforms" directory. can anyone help me how to overcome from this error

Tags: android-studio

NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\LEGION\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NDK is missing a "platforms" directory. while trying to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741528/ndk-is-missing-a-platforms-directory-while-trying-to-build)