# Will cmake compiled TFLite work on android?

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, cmake, android-ndk

I'm making a project with 2 variations, a desktop version and an android version. Both of them are using the same c++ code base. I want to use TFLite without getting into any android configuration like gradle or an aar file. I just want a pure .so file that my c++ can use thus android can through ndk. I know there are some complications like ndk using clang and requiring arm64 architecture, but I think it should be possible. Note that my project requires ndk version 22 and above.

Here is how I configured tflite for my desktop/debian project:

1. On ~/Desktop/ I ran `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow_src`
2. `mkdir tflite_build` & `cd ~/Desktop/tflite_build`
3. `cmake ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite`
4. `cmake --build .` I've removed the `-J` flag regardless of what the docs says because it causes my pc to freeze.
5. `mkdir ~/Desktop/tf_test` & `cd ~/Desktop/tf_test`
6. Create a CMakeLists.txt and a main.cpp file inside `tf_test`directory.
7. Put the main code from the minimal example on the github repo provided above then this code in CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(minimal C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DTFLITE_DISABLE_TELEMETRY=1")

set(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR "" CACHE PATH
  "Directory that contains the TensorFlow project" )
if(NOT TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR)
  get_filename_component(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR
    "/home/user/Desktop/tensorflow_src" ABSOLUTE)
endif()

add_subdirectory(
  "${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

add_executable(minimal minimal.cc)
target_link_libraries(minimal tensorflow-lite)
```

8. Created the folder `tf_Test/build` and ran `cmake ..` inside it.
9. After cmake is completed I run `make` inside the build directory

This works just fine on debian. However when I try to add this to my cmake on my android ndk project, connect my tablet and run the project I get all these errors:

```
...
- Looking for strtoull_l - found
-- Using toolchain file: /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake.
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -frtti -fexceptions -fvisibility=hidden -std=c++17 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pthread -frtti -fexceptions
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3.9 (found suitable version "3.9.2", minimum required is "3.5") found components: Interpreter 
-- Downloading pthreadpool to /home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/pthreadpool-source (define PTHREADPOOL_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/pthreadpool-download/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
-- The ASM compiler identification is Clang with GNU-like command-line
-- Found assembler: /home/user/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.0.8775105/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang
-- Downloading FP16 to /home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/FP16-source (define FP16_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/FP16-download/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
-- Downloading FXdiv to /home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/FXdiv-source (define FXDIV_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/FXdiv-download/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
-- RUY is enabled.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMake Warning at /home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/abseil-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:70 (message):
  A future Abseil release will default ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD to ON for CMake
  3.8 and up.  We recommend enabling this option to ensure your project still
  builds correctly.


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
No such file or directory
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was:  && 
CMake Error at /home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/CMakeLists.txt:167 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source
  "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/pthreadpool-source"
  which is not an existing directory.


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
No such file or directory
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was:  && 
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
No such file or directory
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was:  && 
CMake Error at /home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/xnnpack/CMakeLists.txt:844 (ADD_SUBDIRECTORY):
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY given source
  "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/pthreadpool-source"
  which is not an existing directory.


CMake Error at /home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/xnnpack/CMakeLists.txt:884 (ADD_SUBDIRECTORY):
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY given source
  "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/FXdiv-source"
  which is not an existing directory.


CMake Error at /home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/xnnpack/CMakeLists.txt:908 (ADD_SUBDIRECTORY):
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY given source
  "/home/user/Desktop/native/examples/android/app/.cxx/Debug/5c1w1z3w/arm64-v8a/FP16-source"
  which is not an existing directory.
```

What's the right way to approach this? Following the android build documentation on tflite's website causes a lot of [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75308752/build-tensorflow-lite-on-ndk-22).

Update:
Installing ninja fixed almost all my problems, the only error I have now is:

```
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/python_error_reporter.cc:16:
/home/user/Desktop/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/python_error_reporter.h:19:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
```

python3 is in fact installed on my system, I used it on a c code before.

Update: Adding this to top of my cmake solved the python issue:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/include/python3.9 -I/usr/include/python3.9  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-RNBry6/python3.9-3.9.2=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Wall")
```

Update:
Now I get:

```
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/SmartAlpha/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/numpy.cc:17:
In file included from /home/user/Desktop/SmartAlpha/official_stuff/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/numpy.h:49:
In file included from /usr/include/python3.9/Python.h:8:
/usr/include/python3.9/pyconfig.h:9:12: fatal error: 'aarch64-linux-gnu/python3.9/pyconfig.h' file not found
```

Comment: ***CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".*** Should be something you can easily fix.

Comment: Also I've mentioned this already in your previous post, but `-DTFLITE_DISABLE_TELEMETRY=1` does nothing as this define is no where to be found in the `TFLITE` repo

Comment: @MilanŠ. you are right, I just forgot to delete it, I copy and paste the code.

Comment: @Turgut the new error is most likely related to the fact that when building for Android you don't have a python interpreter/python development packages. Refer to the TFLite official documentation regarding this.

Comment: @MilanŠ. Can you provide a link please?

Comment: @Turgut I'm not a TFlite expert, I will update my answer with a possible solution, but the rest is up to you to figure out really.

Comment: @MilanŠ. Thank you, you have been really helpful so far already. I will accept the answer as soon as I can fix the issue. My only concern was to know whether the tflite I compile on my debian machine will work similarly on an android device. Seeing those errors gone I think I'm on a good start.

Comment: It's really not about getting "accepted answers", the reputation system is somewhat of a joke. It's about providing you with enough information so you can figure it out on your own and even better - learn from it.

Comment: @MilanŠ. I really didn't know android was unix based, I thought it was it's own thing completely seperate from everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LAST EDIT:** You seem to completely overlook what I'm trying to explain you the whole time about **different architectures**. Your phone is not running on the same cpu architecture as your desktop. Your desktop machine is most likely running on **amd64**, while your phone is most likely **arm64** which is also known as **Aarch64** (do you now see what the latest error means? - It can't find the appropriate packages for the correct architecture - you can see that from the path in the error message).

You installed the `amd64` package by issuing `sudo apt-get install python-dev` not the `arm64` package. **[Check this official debian wiki on how to use MultiArch packages](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)**

You need to:

- Update your system so that it can download the packages for different architectures
- And `sudo apt-get install python-dev:arm64`

---

**EDIT:** Regarding the error in the updated question, you are most likely missing python development packages. Since you are on `Debian` I've looked for a possible package of interested and this might be it:
**[python-dev](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-dev)**, try to `apt-get` it for the correct architecture that you need and maybe it will resolve your issues.

---

1. Make sure that Ninja is installed. CMake is trying to use it - **this confuses a lot of users as they most commonly use Makefiles and don't know that an alternative exists.** I don't see you explicitly stating that you use **CMake + Ninja** and hence I mention it.
2. If you have **Ninja** installed then the issue is most likely caused by the fact that it can't resolve the path via just the executable name. Take a look at [CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM.html) to better understand what I mean.

If **2.** is your issue then you can try and set the whole path to this `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` variable, i.e. `set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM /absolute/path/to/bin/ninja)` and see if resolves the issue.

Comment: Cosnidering I do everything with ninja and fix cmake, will the compiled version work on android? That's my real concern.

Comment: Installing ninja fixed majority of my problems. However I'm getting a  new error now which I have updated the question for.

Comment: As long as you link everything as you should there shouldn't be any issues. Android is just another "linux distro" after all

Comment: Python-dev did not solve the issue, I'll try to include python in my cmake, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @Turgut Make sure you download it for the right architecture and that it is available via androids toolchain file. It is 100% related to `python-dev` - if you check the contents of the installed package you will find `Python.h`

Comment: Yea it shows that file instantly, but like I said I've used Python.h on a C++ project before. Maybe It's because of the android toolchain? I kinda don't know how to update it tho... Also adding python to cmake didn't work

Comment: I've fixed the issue and updated the question accordingly, I'm wating for the compilation at the moment but it seems to be going smoothly.

Comment: @Turgut android phones don't run on `amd64` architecture. You using it means nothing, if there is a dependency on the same library but for a different `architecture` then you can't use it

Comment: And I faced another error. Which I think happened because of what you just commented

Comment: @Turgut how did you install the `python-dev` package? I'm sorry to inform you but if you won't answer my questions with the appropriate details I won't be able to help you.

Comment: Of course, I did install it when you updated the answer the first time

Comment: **HOW**, what is the exact command you used?

Comment: I tried both `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and `sudo apt install python-dev`, Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes... and this is what I'm explaining to you the whole time. I'll update my answer for the last time.

Comment: Oh you are right, I completely missed I'm terribly sorry. I tried following the instructions on the link you provided and ran `sudo apt-get install python-dev:arm64` which resulted in apt not finding the package. I tried running `sudo apt-get install libpython3-dev:arm64
` which did install but the problem is still there.